# addSeriesAsDrilldown not working

Tags: highcharts

Why is this code not working? i'm getting a blank after clicking a piece in my pie chart..

```
drilldown: function (e) {

var selectedPoint = e.point; 
var chart = this;


highChart_data = JSON.parse('{"' + e.point.name + '":{ "name": "' + e.point.name + '", "data": [{ "y": 426, "name": "2015-11-08 00:00:00" }, { "y": 229, "name": "2015-11-09 00:00:00" }] }}');


chart.(selectedPoint, highChart_data); }
```

my drilldown property for each data point is set to 'true'.
i have also tried setting it to a unique id and using it in an id attribute of my addSeriesAsDrilldown json.  and nothing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, but a couple of issues: http://jsfiddle.net/qfb4uxnj/

Here is a problem:

```
chart.(selectedPoint, highChart_data);
```

Should be:

```
chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(selectedPoint, highChart_data[selectedPoint.name]);
```

You should pass as an argument `series` object. Not object of series with key-object pair.

Comment: the addSeriesAsDrilldown was accidently removed when i pasted here. i have it in my code.   i see what you did about the series object. thanks i'll try

Comment: ok i did that. now when i click i get the drilldown data. but when i press the "back to 'series'" button i see only the slice that was last selected. the rest are blank even though that their names appear..

Comment: Hmm.. for me it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/qfb4uxnj/1/ - could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? I will check this.

Comment: No because my data is dynamic. for the top level and for the drilldowns. If i hard code it, it will probably work

Comment: Could you try out static data then? I would rather be sure, that the case is async loading, than "probably" :) In general, source of data should not matter at all.

Comment: Ok i found the problem. When i use the highcharts-3d.js and add the options3d configuration to my chart, then it gets screwed up when i hit the back button. if i remove 3d support it's ok.

Comment: Try 4.1.10 version - it should be fixed.